# Accessing the Quality Band for MCD12Q1 with MODISTools GetBands

Tags: r, remote-sensing, modis

I am using MODISTools (https://github.com/seantuck12/MODISTools) to process MCD12Q1 data, which, according to the LP DAAC website (https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mcd12q1), has 16 bands. I believe one of them is a quality band (Land Cover QC). However, when I use the MODISSubsets function to download MCD12Q1 and the GetBands function to view the bands, only 15 bands are returned (without the Land Cover QC band). Without this band, I can't use the MODISSummaries function. Does anyone know how to work around this issue?

Answer (score 4):

It is easy to extract needed subdatasets from HDF with GDAL command line tools.  I guess you might want to do everything in R so here is how they can be run from it. In R there is a package called [gdalUtils](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdalUtils/index.html) it provides wrappers for GDAL tools. You'll need `gdal_translate` for data conversion.

Example:

```r
library(gdalUtils)
hdf4_dataset <- file.choose() #select your HDF
gdal_translate(hdf4_dataset,"modis_qa.tif",sd_index=1)
```

You can then read it with another R package [rgdal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html):

```
library(rgdal)
d <- file.choose() #select your saved GeoTIFF
x = new("GDALReadOnlyDataset", test)
```

Now manipulate x to your liking it is just a data.frame.

You might wonder why not use `rgdal` only. The problem is that it doesn't read HDF format which is used to distribute MODIS data.

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be achieved using the **MODIS** package which is currently hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/MatMatt/MODIS). Install the package via

```
library(devtools)
install_github("MatMatt/MODIS")
library(MODIS)
```

and make sure to adjust the local output filepaths via `MODISoptions`. A more detailed description of the installation procedure can e.g. be found [here](https://stevemosher.wordpress.com/modis-for-r/).

Next, download a desired MCD12Q1 tile using

```
getHdf("MCD12Q1", begin = "2013-01-01", 
       tileH = 21, tileV = 9)
```

and, finally, list the scientific datasets (SDS) included therein using

```
fls <- list.files(getOption("MODIS_localArcPath"), 
                  pattern = "MCD12Q1.A2013001.*.hdf",
                  recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

getSds(fls)
```

As seen from the console output, the 11th SDS is the desired 'Land Cover Type QC' layer, which can subsequently be extracted using

```
runGdal("MCD12Q1", begin = "2013-01-01", 
        tileH = 21, tileV = 9, 
        SDSstring = "0000000000100000")
```

Note that `runGdal` is also a wrapper function around `getHdf`, meaning that if the desired MCD12Q1 tile has not been previously downloaded, `runGdal` will automatically perform the download and extract the desired SDS layers.